# Add a list of all id-s of a many to many relationship to the JSON response

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I want to add all the **`id`**-s of a many-to-many-relationship to my serialized JSON response.

```
class TestField(serializers.Field):
   def to_native(self, value):
       list = []
       for boss in value.all():
           list.append(value).append(';')
       return list

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   test = TestField('test')

   class Meta:
       model = Employee
       fields = ('id', 'test', 'bosses')
       depth = 1
```

So what I want to achieve is: I want to have all of the **`bosses`** of the **`Employee`** in the response, along with an additional a list of all their **`id`**-s, separated by **`;`**.

I've tried using the custom file I created, but for some reason I keep getting the following error.

> AttributeError at /employees/
>
> '`Employee`' object has no attribute '`test`'

What does this error mean and how can I fix my code to give me a list of the **`id`**-s?

Comment: Can you include the model (with the M2M) that you want to serialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST framework [provides a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) that allows you to serialize a relation as a list of primary keys, which sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    test = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        many=True,
        source='relation'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'test', 'bosses')
        depth = 1
```

This will serialize the list of primary keys as `test`. The primary keys are the same as the primary keys of the objects returned by `employee.relation.all()` (because [the `source` is set to `"relation"`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)).